# showing suggestions for spell checker in content-editable div

Tags: javascript, html, spell-checking, right-click

I am developing spell checker for an Indian Language. So far the spell checker is able to find the wrongly spelt words.

I am using a content-editable div for this purpose.So now I need to show the suggestions for wrongly spelt words whenever the user right clicks or selects the wrong word suggestions are to be shown to replace with the wrongly spelt words or simply ignore it.

Iam having a suggestion generator algorithm in perl. I just need to link with `javascript` .Iam stuck in how to show the suggestions(draw the menu at the cursor).I found some code after searching Google.But could not go further.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //here you draw your own menu
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu");
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you precise your question: is your problem to draw the menu where the cursor is? Or is it to show the suggestions related to the word where the cursor is? Or both? :)

Comment: @Djizeus My question is to draw the menu at the cursor

Comment: @Raju so what is the difference with this other question from you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559003/menuitem-and-contextmenu-crossbrowser-compatability ?

Comment: After some time in Google I had created a menu using javascript.Its not working in google-chrome but is working well in firefox.

Comment: Then you should either close this question if the remaining problem is in the other question, or edit your question to state what the problem is exactly.

Comment: @Djizeus How can I close this question without related answers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery to compromise your goal. I've created a very simple example, but with a bit of effort you could make it as you want to(prevent multiple contextmenu's, styling, load the items dynamically, ...).

**HTML**
`<div id="context">lalalalala</div>`

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#context').on('contextmenu', function(e){
        var content = $('#context').html();
        var temp = content + 
                   '<div style="background-color: #CCC; color: #000; width: 150px; padding: 5px;">\
                        <h4>Suggestions</h4>\
                            <ul class="suggestions">\
                                <li>first suggestion</li>\
                                <li>second suggestion</li>\
                                <li>third suggestion</li>\
                            </ul>\
                    </div>';
        $('#context').html(temp);

        $('.suggestions li').on('click', function(e){
            $('#context').html($(this).text());
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4gWjM/

Comment: Good answer the kind of one I need

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `spellcheck="true"` on your `div`

Ex. `<div  spellcheck="true"><input type="text" name="fname" ></div>`

[Reference site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_spellcheck)

[Reference site 2](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/)

**Edit**: I forget to give the link of the second one

Comment: Actually I want to add the suggestions created by my algorithm to the right click menu.
Giving spell check =true will give browsers suggestions.

Comment: Question asker said: `So far the spell checker is able to find the wrongly spelt words.`. The code you give does the same, now he asks: `So now I need to show the suggestions for wrongly spelt words whenever the user right clicks or selects the wrong word suggestions are to be shown to replace with the wrongly spelt words or simply ignore it.`.

Comment: @SagarPanchal can you give some reference sites for giving suggestions in through right click menu.The one you referenced has its own suggestions.

Comment: @SagarPanchal I checked it. It has its own suggestion generation.

Comment: @Raju, you want your own suggestion list ?

Comment: Yes and Iam stuck at showing in them in right click menu

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/974Dm/

It doesn't build the whole menu, but it does give you the misspelled word on right click.

```
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");

editor.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
    var misspelling = event.target;

    while (misspelling && misspelling.className != "misspelled") {
        misspelling = misspelling.parentNode;
    }

    if (misspelling) {
        // Show your suggestions menu
        // misspelling is <span class="mispelled">abc</span>
        console.log("Show suggestions for " + misspelling.innerHTML, misspelling);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Update: In order to create the suggestions menu, you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: Iam stuck at showing suggestions menu @Greg Burghardt

Comment: Hey @Raju! I think this is a good way to go. You just need to use some plugin to actually render drop-down menus for misspelled words. You can use something like this: http://jqueryui.com/menu/ for example. And you can load list of suggestions via AJAX as Greg proposed.

Comment: @SlavaFominII I was already using AJAX and now i had created my menu using document.createElement('menu') which is not working in chrome.
Link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559003/menuitem-and-contextmenu-crossbrowser-compatability